# How can I design an appropriate table if I want a group to have permission to operate multiple files?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, entity-relationship, rdbms

## What I want to do

I want to define an appropriate table definition that satisfies the following.

- I want to use RDBMS (PostgreSQL)
- group table has permissions to operate multiple files
- There are two operating permissions that the group wants to have: read and edit

## What I'm thinking

First I tried to have two columns in the groups table, one to hold multiple readable file ids (column name: can_read_file_ids) and one to hold multiple writable file ids (column name: can_edit_file_ids)

However, I thought that one column should not have multiple values (many-to-many relationship), so I decided to prepare two intermediate tables each and one files table.

The following is the ER diagram described in mermaid and its image

```
erDiagram
    groups ||--o{ can_read_group_files: ""
    groups ||--o{ can_edit_group_files: ""
    files ||--o{ can_read_group_files: ""
    files ||--o{ can_edit_group_files: ""
    groups {
        int id PK
        string name "Name of group"
    }
    can_read_group_files {
        int id PK
        int group_id FK
        int file_id FK "Readable file ID"
    }
    can_edit_group_files {
        int id PK
        int group_id FK
        int file_id FK "Editable file ID"
    }
    files {
        int id PK
        string name
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mfAC.png)

I then thought of adding a permissons table, with only one intermediate table, and adding a permissons_id column. This way, I thought, it would be possible to handle more permissions in the future. (For now, only read and edit permissions are needed.)

The following is the ER diagram described in mermaid and its image

```
erDiagram
    groups ||--o{ group_files: ""
    permissions ||--o{ group_files: ""
    files ||--o{ group_files: ""
    groups {
        int id PK
        string name "Name of group"
    }
    group_files {
        int id PK
        int group_id FK
        int file_id FK "ID of file"
        int permisson_id FK
    }
    permissions {
        int id PK
        string name
        string description
    }
    files {
        int id PK
        string name
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgXns.png)

## What I want to know

I would like to know two things

- Can I set more than 4 columns in the intermediate table? (In the second ER diagram, I set up three columns for foreign keys.)
- Which table definition should I adopt? Or is there a better table definition?